# Inconvenient render partial view MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, partial-views

I have a partial view of work with a viewmodel, but I have a inconvenience when rendering a partial view in the main view

I get the following message:

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type ‘RolMVC3.Models.USER’ but this dictionary requires a model item of type ‘RolMVC3.Areas. Distributor.Models. LocationViewModel ‘**

View Model(LocationViewModel), the ViewModel is within an Area

```
namespace RolMVC3.Areas.Distributor.Models
{
    public class LocationViewModel
        {  
            [Required]
            public decimal IdDepartment { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string NameCity { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string NameNeighborhood { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Partial View(_LocationEdit):

```
 @model RolMVC3.Areas.Distributor.Models.LocationViewModel 
                   .....
                   .....
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdDepartment)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdDepartment, new SelectList(ViewBag.Department as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "IdDepartment", "NameDepartment", ViewBag.selectedDepartment), "--- Select ---", new { id = "Department"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Idepartment)
        </div>
                 .....
                 .....
```

Main View(Edit):

```
@model RolMVC3.Models.USER

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit User";
}

        ....
        ....

@{Html.RenderPartial("_LocationEdit");}

        ....
        ....
```

How I can resolve this?

Blessings

Answer (score 0):

When you call your RenderPartial you need to pass in a model type of LocationViewModel. It doesn't look like you have this in your edit view right now, so you need to either a) add it to the viewbag from your controller and pass it via your RenderPartial call or b) change the model type in your edit view (you may need a wrapper that holds both the user and locationviewmodel information)

**[Edit]**
The source code would looks something like the following:

```
// ViewModel
namespace RolMVC3.Areas.Distributor.Models

    {
        public class EditPageViewModel
        {  
            public LocationViewModel LocationViewModel {get;set;]
            public USER User { get; set; }
        }

    }


// Edit View
    @model RolMVC3.Areas.Distributor.Models.EditPageViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Edit User";
    }

            ....
            ....

    @Html.RenderPartial("_LocationEdit",Model.LocationViewModel);

            ....
            ....
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Main View(Edit) pass the LocationViewModel , because partial view requires this model and you are not passing it in `@Html.RenderPartial`

```
@model RolMVC3.Models.USER

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit User";
}

        ....
        ....

@{Html.RenderPartial("_LocationEdit",YourLocationViewMODEL);}

        ....
        ....
```

Comment: the ViewModel is within an Area, I did this and does not work `@{Html.RenderPartial("_LocationEdit", RolMVC3.Areas.Distributor.Models.LocationViewModel);}`

Comment: Tell me your USER model contain a LocationViewModel ?

Comment: @{Html.RenderPartial("_LocationEdit",new LocationViewModel(IdDepartment = 1.5,NameCity = "city", NameNeighborhood = "neighborhood"));} try this .. i m not sure about the syntax but thats the way it ll work

Comment: No, USER model is separated from the LocationViewMode

Comment: you have to include locationviewmodel in user model i think to use this.